# Lamellophone Miking techniques?

Tags: untagged

HI! Any ideas on miking techniques for recording an MBIRA in a studio!? akg c414, any other ideas, placement, etc.?! thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which type of mbira you will have - there appear to be a lot of styles and lengths.  If it's very long, I would put a stereo mic directly above (maybe at about 10 - 14 inches), plus a mic to the rear to avoid any hand sounds.  You also want to get a contact mic or (if you don't have one) a small capsule condenser on the resonant surface - you'll get some cool lows off of that which will help you fill out the sound.  What mics do you have available to you?

Comment: thanks VC! it's a good idea to have a rear mic, and mix the 3 signals (up, rear, contact) to get a good sound. 
I read somewhere that small diaphragm condensers are good for the type of transients of the mbira.
maybe a stereo technique could be good idea aswell, MS or ORTF!?



Comment: If you can get a matched pair, I would do an XY setup with a fairly tight angle between them.  